# How can I use drop-down menus and divs professionally?

Tags: javascript, button, web, uinavigationbar

I am making a page with buttons on the top navigation bar, as the messages or notifications buttons on Facebook.

[image: this is how the page looks on load]

When the icon is clicked it changes to this:
[image: when the icon is clicked]

I have done this simply using the onclick function which changes the icon src to that in the second image
and the 'display' property of that violet red pointer and the div with headlines changes to 'block' from 'none'

But this is not how things work. How is this done professionally?

I was looking at Facebook's source code and the link to the icons is a page with this image:

[image]

I have seen similar images in SO and WhatsappWeb's page.. they contain all the icons diagonally.

Can you explain me this? Also how can I do it professionally?

Comment: Professionally, as in getting paid for? Simple, find someone who'll pay for it. Btw. that technique uses sprites.

Comment: "Professionally" is a vague term for sure. The reason these images containing dozens of images (spritemaps) are used in production environments is that it saves on requests and bandwidth. Instead of requesting 20-30 different images, one image is requested, and a portion of it is displayed where appropriate.

Comment: am sorry .with professional I mean, how developers do it?